# Регулярное выражение, удалить переносы и пробелы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как сделать регулярку для Notepad++ (найти - заменить),
чтобы убрать все от > до <. Чтобы каждый INSERT был в 1 строку.

пробовал так, но остаются пробелы
найти: `>\r\n`
заменить: `>`

```
INSERT INTO kon (id, xmldata) VALUES (24, '
<owners>
     <owner>
        <name>name</name>
        <phone>444</phone>
        <email>444.COM</email>
     </owner>
</owners>'
INSERT INTO kon (id, xmldata) VALUES (25, '
<owners>
     <owner>
        <name>name</name>
        <phone>444</phone>
        <email>444.COM</email>
     </owner>
</owners>'
```

Comment: Может, `>\s+<` => `><`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
спасибки, жму руку... можете написать ответ я отмечу. ```>\r\n\s+<``` на ```><```

Comment: значит + означает много раз, а я делал с одним \s

Comment: + означает 1 или более
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
>\s+<
```

на

```
><
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/DxqLRd/1).

**Подробности**

- `>` - символ `>`
- `\s+` - один и более (`+`) пробельных символов (`\s`)
- `<` - символ `<`.